# Field extensions isomorphic as fields but not as vector spaces

Tags: abstract-algebra

I came across an exercise, in which I had to prove, that $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ are isomorphic as vector spaces but not as fields. This is quite an easy exercise, as $-1$ can be represented as $i^2$ over $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ but not as $x^2$ with $x \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$.

However I was wondering, if the statement "two field extensions are isomorphic as fields implies field extensions are isomorphic as vector spaces" is true.

Comment: Hint: Two extensions are isomorphic as vector spaces iff they have the same dimension (which is their degree)

Comment: Ahh ok, I would have to show that two (field-)isomorphic fieldextensions $L_1$ and $L_2$ have the same degree. But that should hold as if $φ: L_1 \rightarrow L_2$ is a fieldisomorphism and $\{a_1, ..., a_n\}$ is a basis of $L_1$, then $φ(a_1), ..., φ(a_n)$ should be a basis of L_2. Is this the right idea for this proof?

Comment: Yes. Though I actually like Anon's answer even better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A field isomorphism of field extensions is necessarily a linear isomorphism considering the field extensions as vector spaces. The definition of a field isomorphism is more restrictive than just a linear isomorphism.